# Oozie hive action with kerberos on HDP-1.3.3

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to execute hive script from oozie hive action on kerberos enabled environment.

Here is my workflow.xml

> ```
> <action name="hive-to-hdfs">
>     <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
>         <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
>         <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
>         <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
>         <configuration>
>             <property>
>                 <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
>                 <value>${queueName}</value>
>             </property>
>         </configuration>
>         <script>script.q</script>
>         <param>HIVE_EXPORT_TIME=${hiveExportTime}</param>
>     </hive>
>     <ok to="pass"/>
>     <error to="fail"/>
> ```

I'm facing issue when trying to connect to hive metastore.

> 6870 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://10.0.0.242:9083
>   Heart beat
>   Heart beat
>   67016 [main] WARN  hive.metastore  - set_ugi() not successful, Likely cause: new client talking to old server. Continuing without it.
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>       at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
>       at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
>       at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
>       at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
>
> 67018 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
>   68018 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Connected to metastore.
>   Heart beat
>   Heart beat
>   128338 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient  - MetaStoreClient lost connection. Attempting to reconnect.
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>       at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
>       at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
>       at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
>       at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
>
> 129339 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://10.0.0.242:9083
>   Heart beat
>   Heart beat
>   189390 [main] WARN  hive.metastore  - set_ugi() not successful, Likely cause: new client talking to old server. Continuing without it.
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>       at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
>       at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
>       at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
>       at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
>
> 189391 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
>   190391 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Connected to metastore.
>   Heart beat
>   Heart beat
>   250449 [main] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer  - org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to fetch table SESSION_MASTER
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:953)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:887)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1083)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1059)

When I disable kerberos security workflow works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable your Oozie Hive action to function on a secured cluster you need to include a `<credentials>` section with a credential of type 'hcat' to your workflow.

Your workflow would then look something like:

```
<workflow-app name='workflow' xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.1'>
    <credentials>
        <credential name='hcat' type='hcat'>
            <property>
                <name>hcat.metastore.uri</name>
                <value>HCAT_URI</value>
            </property>
            <property> 
                <name>hcat.metastore.principal</name>
                <value>HCAT_PRINCIPAL</value>
            </property>
        </credential>
    </credentials>

    <action name="hive-to-hdfs" cred="hcat">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <script>script.q</script>
            <param>HIVE_EXPORT_TIME=${hiveExportTime}</param>
        </hive>
        <ok to="pass"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
</workflow>
```

There is also [Oozie documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_UnifiedCredentialsModule.html) about this feature.